# Django Rest Framework Ordering on a SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Forum Topic model that I want to order on a computed SerializerMethodField, such as vote_count. Here are a very simplified Model, Serializer and ViewSet to show the issue:

```
# models.py
class Topic(models.Model):
    """
    An individual discussion post in the forum
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def vote_count(self):
        """
        count the votes for the object
        """
        return TopicVote.objects.filter(topic=self).count()


# serializers.py
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vote_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_vote_count(self, obj):
        return obj.vote_count()

    class Meta:
        model = Topic


# views.py
class TopicViewSet(TopicMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Topic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TopicSerializer
```

Here is what works:

1. OrderingFilter is on by default and I can successfully order `/topics?ordering=title`
2. The vote_count function works perfectly

I'm trying to order by the MethodField on the TopicSerializer, vote_count like `/topics?ordering=-vote_count` but it seems that is not supported. Is there any way I can order by that field?

My simplified JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "first post",
    "voteCount": 1
},
{ 
    "id": 2,
    "title": "second post",
    "voteCount": 8
},
{ 
    "id": 3,
    "title": "third post",
    "voteCount": 4
}
```

I'm using Ember to consume my API and the parser is turning it to camelCase. I've tried ordering=voteCount as well, but that doesn't work (and it shouldn't)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is not possible using [the default `OrderingFilter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter), because the ordering is implemented *on the database side*. This is for efficiency reasons, as manually sorting the results can be *incredibly* slow and means breaking from a standard `QuerySet`. By keeping everything as a `QuerySet`, you benefit from the built-in filtering provided by Django REST framework (which generally expects a `QuerySet`) and the built-in pagination (which can be slow without one).

Now, you have two options in these cases: figure out how to retrieve your value on the database side, or try to minimize the performance hit you are going to have to take. Since the latter option is very implementation-specific, I'm going to skip it for now.

In this case, you can use [the `Count` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#id7) provided by Django to do the count on the database side. This is provided as part of [the aggregation API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) and works like [the SQL `COUNT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx). You can do the equivalent `Count` call by modifying your `queryset` on the view to be

```
queryset = Topic.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('topicvote_set'))
```

Replacing `topicvote_set` with [your `related_name` for the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) (you have one set, right?). This will allow you to order the results based on the number of votes, and even do filtering (if you want to) because it is available within the query itself.

This would require making a slight change to your serializer, so it pulls from the new `vote_count` property available on objects.

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vote_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
```

This will override your existing `vote_count` method, so you may want to rename the variable used when annotating (if you can't replace the old method).

---

Also, you can pass a method name as the `source` of a Django REST framework field and it will automatically call it. So technically your current serializer could just be

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vote_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
```

And it would work *exactly* like it currently does. Note that `read_only` is required in this case because a method is not the same as a property, so the value cannot be set.

Answer (score 3):

I will put it here because the described case is not the only one.
The idea is to rewrite the list method of your Viewset to order by any of your **SerializerMethodField**(s) also without moving your logic from the Serializer to the ModelManager (especially when you work with several complex methods and/or related models)

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().list(request, args, kwargs)
    ordering = request.query_params.get('ordering')
    
    if "-" in ordering:      
        response.data['results'] = sorted(response.data['results'], key=lambda k: (k[ordering.replace('-','')], ), reverse=True)
    else:
        response.data['results'] = sorted(response.data['results'], key=lambda k: (k[ordering], ))

    return response
```

Comment: awesome! would be nice to see a fuller example with a whole viewset and a whole serializer sorting by a SerializerMethodField

Comment: What is `YourModelList` if we are overriding the list method on a viewset?

Comment: is this still good if there is a django LimitOffset pagination set?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @[Kevin Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359284/kevin-brown) for your great explanation and answer!

In my case I needed to sort a serializerMethodField called `total_donation` which is the `sum` of donations from the UserPayments table.

`UserPayments` has:

- `User` as a foreignKey
- `sum` which is an `IntegerField`
- `related_name='payments'`

I needed to get the total donations per User but only donations that have a status of 'donated', not 'pending'. Also needed to filter out the payment_type `coupon`, which is related through two other foreign keys.

I was dumbfounded how to join and filter those donations  and then be able to sort it via `ordering_fields`.

Thanks to your post I figured it out!
I realized it needed to be part of the original `queryset` in order to sort with `ordering`.

All I needed to do was annotate the queryset in my view, using `Sum()` with filters inside like so:

```
class DashboardUserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    donation_filter =  Q(payments__status='donated') & ~Q(payments__payment_type__payment_type='coupon')
    queryset = User.objects.annotate(total_donated=Sum('payments__sum', filter=donation_filter ))
    serializer_class = DashboardUserListSerializer
    pagination_class = DashboardUsersPagination
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['created', 'last_login', 'total_donated' ]
    ordering = ['-created',]
```