# DRF annotate nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a nested serializer initialized with `many=True` and would like to add a number of annotated fields to the output using `SerializerMethodField()`.

How can I annotate the `OrderLineSerializer` queryset without [overriding the manager's default `get_queryset` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49716546/8741781)?

```
class OrderLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    annotated_field_1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    annotated_field_2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    annotated_field_3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine
        fields = (
            'annotated_field_1',
            'annotated_field_2',
            'annotated_field_3',
        )

    def get_annotated_field_1(self, instance):
        return str(instance.annotated_field_1)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lines = OrderLineSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id'
            'lines'
        )

class OrderAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Why don't you annotate it when you define the `queryset` value in the `OrderAPIViewSet`?

Comment: @LucaBezerra the model in `OrderAPIViewSet` is `Order`, I'm trying to annotate the `OrderLine` model. I've added some more code to hopefully make the question clearer.

Comment: Do you need these fields to be computed by the DB? If not, I suggest you add one @property to your `OrderLine` model for each of the so called _annotated_ fields that return the proper values and declare one `ReadOnlyField` for each of those properties in the `OrderLineSerializer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` in your `OrderSerializer`. Something like this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lines = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_lines(self, instance):
        annotated_lines = instance.lines.annotate(annotated_field_1=...)
        return OrderLineSerializer(annotated_lines, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id'
            'lines'
        )
```

This feels *weird* though, is this something you truly need to do with annotation rather than with a `property`, for example?

Comment: `instance.annotated_field` causes a query for each instance in the queryset, using annotations does not.