# Can I annotate onto a select_related() field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to annotate how many cars each owner owns as an optimization.

This may seem like an odd way to do this, but I'm using Django Rest Framework and the serialized `Car` has an `Owner` field, and the `Owner` serialization contains a dynamically calculated count of how many cars the user owns.

This is *sort of* what I want...

`cars = Car.objects.select_related('owner').annotate(owner__cars_count=Count('owner__car'))`

...except what I want is `cars[0].owner.cars_count` not `cars[0].owner__cars_count`.  I want to annotate the *owner*, not the *car* so that DRF has the field available when it serializes the owner.

Swapping out `objects` in `Owner` isn't going to work either because `select_related` doesn't on `Car` doesn't use the `Owner` manager.

This is spookily similar to [Nested annotate fields in Django REST Framework serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964820/nested-annotate-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers), but the accepted answer does what I'm already doing -- calculating it per record in a `SerializerMethodField`.  A not accepted answer describes doing this with `prefetch_related` not `select_related`.

Since this is DRF, alternatively perhaps I can copy the annotation from `Car.owner__cars_count` to `Car.owner.cars_count` before it gets to the nested serializers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Prefetch class:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Prefetch

cars = Car.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('owner', Owner.objects.annotate(cars_count=Count('car'))))

for car in cars:
    print(car.owner.cars_count)
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I didn't realize you could `prefetch` a foreign key -- I thought it was for many relationships. `prefetch_related('owner')` ends up with two queries, but it's still better than the alternative.