# Ordering on SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There is a Video model that I wish to order on a SerializerMethodField. The fields on which the ordering needs to be done is votes and likes, for which I am using additional django packages, 'votes' and 'django-hitcount'.

```
#models.py
class Video(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    '''
    Other properties
    '''
    votes = VotableManager()

#serializer.py
class VideoListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    views = SerializerMethodField()
    likes = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = [
            'title',
            'views',
            'likes'
        ]

    def get_likes(self, obj):
        return list(Video.objects.get(pk=obj.id).votes.likes()).count(True)

    def get_views(self, obj):
        return Video.objects.get(pk=obj.id).hit_count.hits

#API View for Most Viewed Videos
class VideoMostViewedAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VideoListSerializer
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter]
```

1. I can successfully order using the API endpoint: /videos/?ordering=title
2. get_likes and get_views functions work fine.

I'm trying to order using both 'views' and 'likes' SerializerMethodField on the VideoListSerializer like /videos/most-viewed/?ordering='-likes' but it doesnt seem to work. Is there any way I can order by that field?

I have already had a look at this question: [Django Rest Framework Ordering on a SerializerMethodField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041948/django-rest-framework-ordering-on-a-serializermethodfield) but somehow, it doesnt help me solve my problem.

I have also tried to use Count with annotate() method for aggregation, but I can also use a field value, eg, 'votes' rather than doing something like votes.likes(), which is obviously not possible.

---

### EDIT 1

I have used external django packages for both views and likes/dislikes. So, votes.likes() actually returns a list containing true and false.

Eg- if suppose I had an API call,

```
/api/votes/up/?model=video&id=15&vote=true
```

then the request user will have voted for the video model object with id=15. Similarly doing

```
/api/votes/likes/?model=video&id=15
```

will return the likes and dislikes of video model object of id=15, same as using votes.likes() in my serializer.

Also, since I want only likes, I do list(instance.votes.likes()).count(True) to count only votes which are True(i.e, upvoted).

Similarly, for calculating views, I am using hit_count property of the model which isn't defined by me but available via adding the HitCountMixin and I return the hits from it.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about how your votes.likes() method looks like what is hit_count.hits, how your models are structured, so we can help you with the annotate method, because your best bet is annotating the queryset. (And I think it shouldn't be that hard either)

Comment: @Nirri I have updated the details of using votes and views in my model. I still cant figure out how to annotate it though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to give you an idea how to start, you will have to dig a little deeper into those packages you are using.

As far as I was able to figure out for django-hitcount, there's a HitCount model with content_object as the foreign key to your Video. It has a PositiveIntegerField named hits that contains the number of hits for your objects. Since it's a foreign key you might have to run it through Max or something of the like.
See their models.py for more info [here](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/297b84279e2e52f1a9a6b885eb66fdc3b39feadc/hitcount/models.py).

And for django-vote, there's an instance of a Vote class for every vote your object received. It is also connected to your Video object through a GenericForeignKey relation. So you're good just counting those.
See their models.py for more info [here](https://github.com/tixdo/votes/blob/master/votes/models.py).

Let me know how it goes.