# How to sort values of serializer custom field in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a custom field in the client serializer.
The value of this field is calculated by a complex serializer method.

```py
class ClientsStatsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer shows total_spend for 2019 by client.
    """
    refs_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_spend_2019 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        ordering = ('total_spend_2019',)
        fields = [
            'id',
            'legal_name',
            'refs_count',
            'total_spend_2019',
        ]
        def get_total_spend_2019(self, obj):
            ...
```

I would like to get the output sorted by the value of `total_spend_2019`. It looks like I cannot do it here with a simple `ordering = ('total_spend_2019',)` I cannot do it either in the model, neither in the view.

EDIT: It would be great to have a generic solution that would work with any SerializerMethodField.

Current view is as such:

```py
class ClientsStatsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = request.user.company.clients.all()

        client_id = self.request.query_params.get('client_id', None)
        if client_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=client_id)

        serializer = ClientsStatsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework Ordering on a SerializerMethodField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041948/django-rest-framework-ordering-on-a-serializermethodfield)

Answer (score 7):

All right, I managed to solve it with the following:

```py
class ClientsStatsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = request.user.company.clients.all()

        client_id = self.request.query_params.get('client_id', None)
        if client_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=client_id)

        serializer = ClientsStatsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        serializer_data = sorted(
            serializer.data, key=lambda k: k['total_spend_2019'], reverse=True)
        return Response(serializer_data)
```

I don't know if it is the most performant way to do this, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try create your custom model manager. This is popular decision for ordering data:

```py
models.py

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(...).order_by(...)


class Company(models.Model):
    ...

   objects = models.Manager
   custom_manager = CustomManager()


views.py

class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    ...
    queryset = Company.custom_manager.all()
    ...
```