# Ordering in serializer custom field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My variable inside a serializer
MySerializer.

```
du = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_du(self, obj):

   modelname = Somemodel.objects.filter('id=id')
   du = sum(modelname.values_list('t', flat=True))
   return du
```

I want to return response in descending order as per value of du.
My View:

```
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Anothermodel.objects.all()
        serializer = MySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({"organization": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it with help [How to sort values of serializer custom field in DRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942068/how-to-sort-values-of-serializer-custom-field-in-drf)

```
serializer_data = sorted(serializer.data, key=lambda k: k['du'], reverse=True)
        return Response({"info": serializer_data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use .order_by()? Something like:

```
AnotherModel.objects.all().order_by('-du')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: du is just a serializermethodfield() .It doesn't exist as a column in AnotherModel.

Comment: Have you thought about using sorted()? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html