How to apply ordering based on another model field data in DRF?
I am trying to develop an API to filter JobApplication model data, and facing problem to ordering the response data for a custom field.
Here is my JobApplication model.
class JobApplication(models.Model):
    job_post = models.ForeignKey(JobPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_seeker = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applied_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    experience = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

And filter models is:
class JobApplicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    gender = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='job_seeker__personaldetails__gender')    
    age = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='job_seeker__personaldetails__age', lookup_expr='lte')
    experience = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='experience', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = JobApplication 
    fields = ['gender', 'age', 'experience']
   

And the views is:
class JobApplicantFilterListView(generics.ListAPIView):
   
    serializer_class = JobApplicationSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = JobApplicationFilter
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
    ordering_fields = ['age','experience']

Now I want to add a filed as full_name in JobApplicationFilter class, Where full_name field will generate from first_name and last_name fields from PersonaDetails model. And finally use this full_name field to ordering the result.
I have used annotate, but not working[maybe I have missed something].

Does this answer your question? django rest framework ordering non model field(serializer field)

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041948/django-rest-framework-ordering-on-a-serializermethodfield

@HarunYilmaz tnx for ur reply, let me check.
